# Stand alone Datacontainer/Database

Tags: c#, database, dataset, store

I work in a call center and we need to use a lot of web based tools and work with a lot of information. They way we need to work is not efficient, so I made myself a couple of C# Windows Application to make my work a bit easier.

The problem is that those computers a locked en secured in a very high level. Almost all website's are blocked, we can't use USB drives to get data on the pc, the only way to get data to my account at work is to mail it compressed in a 7z file. We can't install software, drivers etc. I luckily have write access to the program data folder to save some data. But the only way I can store data is to put it all in .txt files. I've tried a lot of standalone databases but I'm also limited in space because we've got 30MB. So a standalone version of xampp (or similar software) is almost 40 MB so I can't use it.

Does anybody know I type of database to store my data is (mostly text and integers)? I prefer a single file which i can drop in the program data folder. I prefer it also to get the data in the same way like getting it from a database, dataset or something similar.

Comment: Have you taken a look to .NET isolated storage ? It may be what you're looking for : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ak841sy.aspx

Comment: I've checked the link you commented but I think it's not easy to access data or filter on data (the data I use is like 200 pieces of text and I need to add IDs to them and I need to give them a name and link it with that ID, just like you use a database). The problem is that the computers they use are on .NET 2.0 and it doesn't support linq and much more handy features.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into Infobright Community Edition which can give you incredible compression ratios on average from 40:1.  Infobright is exactly like mysql and very compact.

*Disclaimer: the author is affiliated with Infobright.*